# Why isn't this method getting called from my Rails unobtrusive js template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I recently started using CoffeeScript in my Rails 3.2.14 app. Currently all of our javascript code is jumbled into application.js, which also acts as our manifest file. Our plan was to extract out the stuff into controller specific code so it is easier to maintain in the future. In our `application_helper.rb` file, we have this helper

```
def css_tag_id
  "#{controller.controller_name}-#{controller.action_name}"
end
```

We use this for page specific CSS and JavaScript. So my first step was taking code related to our PostsController and putting it in a new file `posts.js.coffee`. I wrap all the code in `posts.js.coffee` with a check using the `id` on the `body` to ensure the code only runs on views rendered by the PostsController. This all gets compiled into one big application.js file and this is fine with me. This all works perfectly.

However, an AJAX submitted form on one of the pages hits an action in the PostsController which renders `select_customer.js.erb`. In this template, it calls a method that is now defined in `posts.js.coffee`, and for some reason no longer works.

Here is a small example of all the files involved:

**posts.js.coffee:**

```
jQuery ->
  if $('#posts-new').length > 0
    keywordsAccordion()

keywordsAccordion = ->
  $('.accordion').accordion
    'active': 0,
    'collapsible': true
```

**select_customer.js.erb**

```
keywordsAccordion();
```

Is CoffeeScript compiling `posts.js.coffee` so that it is all namespaced or something? And I need to call methods defined in it differently now from other js templates?

I realize this may be terribly confusing, but will be so grateful is someone can help me out.

Comment: I went ahead and just namespaced everything in my `posts.js.coffee` file as Dylan suggested, but instead of attaching everything to the window object, I wrapped all my functions inside `@posts = ` so I can just then reference my posts object which IS attached to the window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each coffeescript file is namespaced so that its functions are only available within the same file. So `keywordsAccordion()` is only accessible within the `posts.js.coffee` file.

You can attach these functions to the `window` object instead, making them available anywhere:

```
window.keywordsAccordion = ->
  ...
```

I believe you can also use `@keywordsAccordion = ->`, which is shorthand for `this.keywordsAccordion = ->` (with `this` referring to the global scope)

Comment: Awesome, I had a hunch it was due to some namespacing I wasn't aware of, so it is nice to know for sure now. Is there a way to explicitly namespace my `posts.js.coffee` file so I can just refer to that from elsewhere? I'd rather not clutter up the global namespace, especially if Rails already handles namespacing each file for me.

Comment: Added a comment to my question @DylanMarkow, thanks for the help man.